# The solution set of this inequality $\sum_{k=1}^{70}\frac{k}{x-k} \ge \frac{5}{4}$

Tags: polynomials, fractions

$$\sum_{k=1}^{70}\frac{k}{x-k} \ge \frac{5}{4}$$
The solution set of this inequality is a union of disjoint intervals and let $S$ be the sum of lengths of intervals of $x$ which satisfy the given inequality, then $S=?$

---

Expanding out gives
$$\frac{1}{x-1}+\frac{2}{x-2}+\frac{3}{x-3} + \dots + \frac{70}{x-70} \ge \frac{5}{4}$$
Also I could just conclude that it will be an equation of degree $70$ but I have no clue on how to approach/solve this problem or what can be the possible values of $x$. Graphing this equation would be really tedious. If anyone can suggest some hints/clues, it would be a great help. Thank You

Comment: For $x=1.01$ the sum is 26.1167>5/4$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe, how did you calculate the whole sum value for $x=1.01$?

Comment: Using some CAS.

Comment: Ya, got that using an online calculator @MichaelHoppe. Similarly $x=2.01, 3.01 \dots$ are also satisfying the conditions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function $f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{x-k}$ is defined on $\Bbb R \setminus \{ 1, 2, \ldots, n \}$, and

- negative on $(-\infty, 1)$,
- strictly decreasing on each interval $(k, k+1)$, $k < n$, with limits $\pm \infty$ at the boundaries of the interval,
- positive and strictly decreasing on $(n, \infty)$ with limits $+\infty$ and zero.

Now fix a number $a > 0$. The set $\{ x \mid f(x) \ge a \}$ is the union of $n$ intervals $(k, x_k]$, where $x_k$ is the unique solution of $f(x) = a$ in $(k, k+1)$ (resp. $(n, \infty)$). The total length is therefore
$$
 S = \sum_{k=1}^n (x_k -k) \, .
$$
Writing the equation $f(x) = a$ in the form
$$
 \prod_{k=1}^n (x-k) - \frac 1a \sum_{k=1}^n \left( k \prod_{l \ne k} (x-l) \right) = 0
$$
and applying Vieta's formulas gives
$$ 
\sum_{k=1}^n x_k = \left( 1 + \frac 1a\right)\sum_{k=1}^n k
$$
and therefore
$$
 S = \frac 1a \sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2a} \, .
$$
In your case is $n=70$ and $a=5/4$, so that the total length is $S=1988$.

---

*Generalization:* The same approach works to compute the solution set of
$$
 \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{b_k}{x-c_k} \ge a
$$
where $a$ and $b_1, \ldots b_n$ are positive real numbers, and $c_1, \ldots, c_n$ are distinct real numbers.

Again the solution set is a union of half-open intervals $[c_k, x_k)$ where $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ are the solutions of
$$
 \prod_{k=1}^n (x-c_k) - \frac 1a \sum_{k=1}^n \left( b_k \prod_{l \ne k} (x-c_k) \right) = 0
$$
and Vieta's formula gives
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n x_k = \sum_{k=1}^n \left( c_k + \frac 1a b_k \right) \, .
$$
The total length of the solution set is therefore
$$
 S = \frac 1a \sum_{k=1}^n b_k \, .
$$
Interestingly, the total length does not depend on the $c_k$.

Comment: Thank you very much @MartinR for your answer. Can you please elaborate a bit more from 'fix a number a', 'where xk is the unique solution'? I am not understanding that part

Comment: @PCMSE: $f$ is strictly decreasing on each interval $(k, k+1)$, with $\lim_{x \to k_+} f(x) = +\infty$ and $\lim_{x \to (k+1)_-} = -\infty$. Therefore $f(x) = a$ has exactly one solution $x_k$ in the interval $(k, k+1)$, and $f(x) \ge a$ for $k < x \le x_k$.

Comment: Somewhat like $\tan x$ @MartinR?

Comment: @PCMSE: Exactly. Or better $\cot(x)$, which is decreasing. Of course we have on ly finitely many intervals here.

Comment: Also you mean intersection of y=f(x) and y=a? Atleast one in (k , k+1) @MartinR

Comment: @PCMSE: Yes, solutions of $f(x) = a$ are the intersections of $y=f(x)$ and $y = a$.

Comment: And a=5/4? @MartinR

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129501/discussion-between-pcmse-and-martin-r).

Answer (score 2):

In my former research group, we worked extensively the problem of the $(n-1)$ solutions of the equation

$$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac {a_i}{x-b_i}-c=0$$ You could find [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0098135414003019) our most recent work where are proposed rapid and robust methods of resolution using convex transformations.

Your case is even simpler since $a_i=b_i$ and you are only concerned by the largest root.

The idea is to consider instead the function
$$g(x)=(x-b_n)\sum_{i=1}^n \frac {a_i}{x-b_i}-c(x-b_n)=0$$ and for you case to expand the first term as a series for infinite values of $x$. This gives with your numbers
$$0=-\frac{5
   x}{4}+\frac{5145}{2}-\frac{57155}{x}-\frac{2000425}{x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)$$

So, using the first and second term, we have $x_0=2058$ and the first iteration of Newton method applied to this very truncated series will give
$$x_1=\frac{44747735067}{21987445}=2035.1494\cdots$$ while the exact solution is $x=2035.1382\cdots$

Comment: *“you are only concerned by the largest root”* –  I do not understand that remark. The sum of *all* roots is needed to compute the total length of the solution set $\{ x \mid f(x) \ge c \}$.